# JavaFX: Как организовать многозадачность?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Есть несколько окон (Stage объектов), в каждом из которых на сцене размещен `webview`. В каждом окне, на `webview` требуется реализовать по отдельному потоку, который будет циклично производить некие операции (переход по URL, заполнение формы на странице и т.д.).

Изначально пробовал реализовать задачу при помощи `Thread`, но, не вышло, ругается, что манипуляции с объектами сцены нужно делать в **JavaFX Application Thread**.

Потом начал смотреть в сторону **JavaFX Task** и **JavaFX Service**. Как понимаю это именно то, что требуется для решения задачи?
В любом случаи, интересно узнать ваше мнение и если можно с краткими примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: Если кратко - то да, это то. Если что-то ругается, что не в том треде делается, обарачивай в Platform.runLater()

Comment: @AndrewBystrov а как быть в случае, если требуется выполнять множество продолжительных операций с различными webview параллельно (для экономии времени)? страницы в webview не загружаются молниеносно, ещё нужно дождаться загрузки страницы, потом проделать какие-то манипуляции с ней. в своей основе как раз именно из таких манипуляций состоит большая часть кода. и если это всё обернуть в Platform.runLater() как минимум для одного webview, то в приложении уже будет постоянно блокироваться интерфейс.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov и вообще как это организовать, не подскажите? :)

Comment: Вы хотите из разных потоков обновлять интерфейс? Так не получится, интерфейс необходимо обновлять в одном потоке. А по поводу организации, советую почитать тут https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm . Ну и запросы в гугле вида javafx concurrency example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь классом Service или Task из javafx.concurrent. Для влияния на свойства элементов интерфейса используйте связывание (binding) свойств для объектов интерфейса.

Логика простая - долгие задачи отправляем в сервис, сервис запускаем в фоновом потоке, в фоновом потоке обновляете состояние свойства (property), с которым связано свойство объекта пользовательского интерфейса.

Пример с Task:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

new Thread(task).start();
```